# Unable to upload image from android to server

Tags: java, php, android

I used this code to upload an image into the server but am getting an exception in log-cat saying Upload file into server exception in MainActivity.java and it is not uploading the image, can some one please explain me where I have gone wrong..

MainActivity.java

```
package com.fm.upload;



import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TextView messageText;
    private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        upLoadServerUri = "http://localhost/file_up/savetofile.php";
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0==btnselectpic)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        }
        else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
             messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                      uploadFile(imagepath);

                 }
               }).start();     
        }

    } 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

        }
    }
         public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                             + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                      +" C:/xampp/htdocs/file_up/uploads";
                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView_pic"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button_selectpic"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Select Picture" />

     <Button
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Click To Upload File"
         android:id="@+id/uploadButton"
     />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text=""
         android:id="@+id/messageText"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textStyle="bold"
     />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer below code :

Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        ListView listview;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myfiles", MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("0", "monika_pin.png");
            editor.putString("1", "monika_pin1.png");
            editor.putString("2", "monika_pin2.png");
            editor.commit();

            String[] arr = new String[] { "/mnt/sdcard/monika_pin.png",
                    "/mnt/sdcard/monika_pin1.png", "/mnt/sdcard/monika_pin2.png" };

            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);

            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem_imv, list);
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            List<String> mList;
            LayoutInflater mInflater;
            int mResource;

            public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
                super(context, resource, objects);

                mResource = resource;
                mInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                mList = objects;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view;

                if (convertView == null) {
                    view = mInflater.inflate(mResource, null);
                } else {
                    view = convertView;
                }

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                imageView.setTag(mList.get(position));// tag of imageView == path to
                                                        // image
                new LoadImage(imageView).execute();
                textView.setText(mList.get(position).toString());

                return view;
            }
        }

        class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

            private ImageView imv;
            private String path;

            public LoadImage(ImageView imv) {
                this.imv = imv;
                this.path = imv.getTag().toString();
            }

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                // File file = new File(
                // Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                // path);
                File file = new File(path);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }

                return bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                if (!imv.getTag().toString().equals(path)) {
                    /*
                     * The path is not same. This means that this image view is
                     * handled by some other async task. We don't do anything and
                     * return.
                     */
                    return;
                }

                if (result != null && imv != null) {
                    imv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imv.setImageBitmap(result);
                } else {
                    imv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

        }

        public void buttonClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }
```

Service :

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    private static final String TAG = "com.example.ServiceExample";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myfiles", MODE_PRIVATE);
        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = "http://myserver/uploadimage.php";

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand " + startId);

        final int currentId = startId;

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    // long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10*1000;

                    // while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {

                            uploadFile(sharedPref.getString(i + "", ""));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }

                    }
                    // }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service running " + currentId);
                }
                stopSelf();
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        // File sourceFile = new
        // File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),sourceFileUri);
        File sourceFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            return 0;

        } else {
            try {

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                // dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""+ fileName + """
                // + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                        "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }

}
```

PHP Script :

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

[COMPLETE SOURCE CODE](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=8fbd3a73d6d8bfc1&id=8FBD3A73D6D8BFC1%21385&ithint=file,.rar&authkey=!AExWDWiDqzlo0S8)